# how to show loading indicator on page loading in angular 7 until all apis response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, css, angular7

I have 5 api calls in a page. some apis take 20 sec to give response. some take 30 sec to give response. some take 10 sec so, when first api gives its response, first api sets loading indicator false. then loading indicator disppears. But other apis are still working I want to show loading indicator until the five api calls response. can you please give me some idea to do the task.

code:

component.ts

```
  loading = true;
  ngInit() {

  this.api1();
  this.api2();
  this.api3();
  this.api4();
  this.api5();

  }

  api1(){
  this.loading=true;
  this.apiService.api1.subscribe(response => {
  loading = false;
  }, error=>{

  });
  }
  api2(){
  this.loading=true;
  this.apiService.api2.subscribe(response => {
  loading = false;
  }, error=>{

  });

  }
  api3(){
  this.loading=true;
  this.apiService.api3.subscribe(response => {
  loading = false;
  }, error=>{

  });
  }
  api4() {
  this.loading=true;
  this.apiService.api4.subscribe(response => {
  loading = false;
  }, error=>{

  });
  }
api5() {
  this.loading=true;
  this.apiService.api5.subscribe(response => {
  loading = false;
  }, error=>{

  });
  }
```

ApiService.service.ts:

```
     api1(): any {

      return this.http.get('apiurl');

    }
    api2(): any {

      return this.http.get('apiurl');

    }
    api3(): any {

      return this.http.get('apiurl');

    }
    api4(): any {

      return this.http.get('apiurl');

    }

    api5(): any {

      return this.http.get('apiurl');

    }
```

Comment: You might want to check out the operator decision tree-app in the docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree

Answer (score 9):

You can use rxjs forkjoin for the same. Forkjoin waits for all the request is complete and return the response when all the api call complete. Here is the example.

```
**component.ts**

isLoading: boolean;
constructor(private apiCallService: ApiSErvice) {}
ngOnInit() {
   this.isLoading = true;
   this.apiCallService.multipleApiCallFunction().subscribe(response  => {
       this.isLoading = false;
})
}


**ApiService.service.ts**

import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

multipleApiCallFunction() : Observable<any[]>{
 const api1 = this.http.get('apiurl-1');
 const api2 = this.http.get('apiurl-2');
 const api3 = this.http.get('apiurl-3');
 const api4 = this.http.get('apiurl-4');

  return forkJoin([api1, api2, api3, api4]);

}
```

Comment: We just did the same last week, nice one

Comment: this is the correct way to do this (i'd place the loading's `true` inside a `tap` operator and the `false` inside a `finalize` block for readability)

Comment: @Yash Rami guys thanks for the solution. can i use interceptor this ?

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal Sir, Interceptor is used for intercepting the request or response but here we have multiple api call so we did't track which api call is complete and which are pending so here we use fork join for the same

Comment: yeah. you are right. boilerplate code will come.  I should put in angular component whereever i need loading = false and loading = true. that is why i asked . please tell me.

Comment: Sir, you can also do one thing before the forkjoin code set isLoading = true and subscribe the forkjoin and inside the forkjoin arrow function you can set the isLoading flag false 

isLoading = true;
forkJoin([api1, api2, api3, api4]).subscribe(response => {
     isLoading = false;
});

Comment: forkJoin is indeed a good options but hope you understand the consequences comes with that if any of the api calls fails you will not get the response from any of the API to display in the template if this scenario is acceptable then go ahead otherwise handle error scenarios nicely @KumaresanPerumal

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question is not active now. However I add the solution here to show spinner if anyone needs in future.

You can use this angular package to show spinner( loader ) whenever you call the api. It's very much helpful to show the spinner on initial load.
You can also use regex's, methods and headers to filter the api's.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-http-loader

Comment: I tried it out and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this if you don't want to use forkJoin or want to control each one individually, you can create a Subscription variable for each API call, and then in your HTML use an *ngIf="sub1 || sub2 || ... || sub5" to display and hide the loading indicator, it will be something like this:

```
//declare subscriptions like so
sub1: Subscription; 

ngInit() {
  sub1 = this.api1();
  sub2 = this.api2();
  sub3 = this.api3();
  sub4 = this.api4();
  sub5 = this.api5();
}
```

in your HTML loading bar tag add:

```
*ngIf="sub1 || sub2 || sub3 || sub4 || sub5"
```

Comment: html code is common for all components. so it is not fesible solution. please tell me any other idea.

Comment: This isn't indicated in your question, and I still don't see why it isn't feasible. What do  you mean by 'html code is common for all components'.

Comment: assume I have another component. That has five api calls , what will you do ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can still do the same :)

Comment: the html is your component's, if u want a variable like your loading boolean, you can check your other sub variables in the subscribe of each api call, if the rest are all null, that means they are finished and u can set the loading boolean to false :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a variable(s) to store API results then load the content based on it's existance:

```html
<div *ngIf = "apiResults; else elseBlock">
    ...
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Loading...</ng-template>
```