# How can i combine data from two API's into datasource

Tags: angular, material-design

I have two different api's in component.ts and i want to display data from them into my `component.html` file table. How can i do?

```
this.dataSource.data = this.agentdata;
this.dataSource.data = this.ratingData;
```

Ì think this will overwrite the already present data.

I want both data in `dataSource.data` and I can easily access it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you post your code as a part of the question

Comment: you can use `rxJs` `forkjoin` for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878352/how-to-show-loading-indicator-on-page-loading-in-angular-7-until-all-apis-respon

Answer (score 3):

Start by merging your stream, and transform it into a datasource. You can then use the `async` pipe to bind it to your HTML.

```
datasource$ = forkJoin(
  this.api.callOne(),
  this.api.callTwo(),
).pipe(
  map([one, two] => new MatTableDatasource([...one, ...two])
);
```

In your HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="datasource$ | async">...</table>
```

As a sidenote, Material provides a high level of abstraction : you should **not** interact with the data source yourself (with `source.data = ...`), but rather create a new datasource everytime.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
this.dataSource.data=this.agentdata.concat(this.ratingData);
```

this will merge two arrays without deleting the duplicates.